# Adding the value from AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-alertdialog

I have to read value either small, medium or large from an AlertDialog. What I want is every size has its own price and every time I add a new size the price will be added.

Answer (score 0):

You can design a separate xml layout for the AlertDialog, or simply use the following code

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
builder.setMessage("Select Size");
builder.setNeutralButton("Large", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //Set large size
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("Medium", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //Set Medium size
    }
});
builder.setPositiveButton("Small", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //Set Small size
    }
});
builder.setCancelable(true);
builder.create();
builder.show();
```